# Closing Safari push notification dialog in Browserstack

Tags: selenium, safari, jasmine, protractor, browserstack

We're using Browserstack to automate testing of my website. The website uses push notifications and so Safari prompts the user with a dialog asking for permission to send push notifications. This dialog blocks interaction with the browser and the test fails. We've tried browser.switchTo().alert().accept() as well as browser.switchTo().window() to close it or switch back to the website, to no avail.

Comment: Hi, I have checked various sources and see that there are no custom capabilities to allow/block the notifications popup in Safari. Issues have been already raised against this. You can read it here: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3862